# How do I prove that every ring is a semiring?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

**Note**: Take note that since I wrote this question approximately a year ago, I have taken a probability theory course.

This isn't a homework assignment. I'm trying to teach myself probability theory this summer and am currently going through the introduction on measure theory in Klenke's *Probability Theory*.

I am trying to prove Theorem 1.12(ii). Klenke does go through some detail, but he does not complete the proof. The statement is:

> *Every $\sigma$-ring is a ring, and every ring is a semiring*.

I have the following:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-ring. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is obviously a ring. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is $\setminus$-closed, by Theorem 1.4., it is $\cap$-closed. Now let $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$. Consider $B \setminus A$...

I need to show that $B \setminus A$ is a finite union of mutually disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$. I've already seen the ProofWiki version of this; however, it uses a different definition. I was considering taking $B \setminus A = B \cap A^{C} = (B^C \cup A)^C$, but alas, $\mathcal{A}$ isn't closed under complements.

Any help is appreciated. (This is my first post here - hope I did this right!)

Comment: You write: $\mathcal A$ is $\setminus$-closed. Hence $B\setminus A$ is the union of **one** set, namely $B \setminus A$ from $\mathcal A$.

Comment: I would assume that $\mathcal{A}$ being a ring means that $B\setminus A\in\mathcal{A}$, which would write it as a disjoint union of elements from $\mathcal{A}$ (specifically, one element: $B\setminus A$).  But this is what the comment from a year ago is saying.  Is "ring" defined in some other manner?

Comment: What I (still) don't understand is how can you make a union of one set, when unions (from the definitions I've learned) usually require at least two sets?

Comment: You’ve learned that a union is a way to combine two or more sets into one.  But there’s nothing that prevents us from talking about a union of one set (which is itself). Similarly, we can talk about the sum of a sequence of length 1 (which gives the element).  Instead of thinking of it as $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\dotsb\cup A_n$, think of it as $\cup_{i=1}^n A_k$, but now we can take $n=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the same question and then was lead to your post here. I think I've figured out a full proof.

Before my written, I list both definitions of Ring and Semiring in Halmos' *Measure Theory*, that is,

A **Ring(or Boolean Ring)** of sets is a non empty class $R$ of sets such that if $$ E ∈ R \ and \ F ∈ R$$ then $$(E ∪ F) ∈ R \ and \ (E - F) ∈ R$$.

A **Semiring** of sets is a non empty class $P$ of Sets such that, if $$A, B ∈P$$ then $$(A ∩ B) ∈ P \ and \ (A - B)∈ P_{Σf}$$ where $P_{Σf} =$ {$A = \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)| A_i ∈ P, A_i ∩ A_j = \emptyset \ for \ i≠j, i,j ∈$ {$i,2,3,...,n$}, $n \ is \ finite$}(Please note **$n$** is **finite**).

**Now begin my proof that is if $C$ is a Ring then try to show it is a Semiring as well.**

Let $G_1$ = {$A' ∈ C| (A' ∩ B) ∈ C, (A' - B) ∈ C_{∑f}, \forall B ∈ C$} then it is clear $G_1 \subset C$.

Let $\forall A' ∈ C$.

Since $\forall B ∈ C$ $=>$ $(A'-B) ∈ C$ $=>$ $\exists D_{A'} ∈ C$ such that $(A'-B) = D_{A'}$. Since $C \subset C_{∑f}$ then $D_{A'} ∈ C_{∑f}$(Actually $D_{A'} = D_{A'} ∪ \emptyset$ that made $D_{A'} ∈ C_{∑f}$). Here we are on halfway to show $C \subset G_1$.

Next since $(A'∩B) = A'-(A'-B)$ and we still have $(A'-B) ∈ C$ due to $A', B ∈ C$, then $(A'∩B) ∈ C$.

So $A' ∈ G_1$.

Since $\forall A'$, then $$C \subset G_1$$.

Combined, $C = G_1$. Since $G_1$ is a Semiring, vacuously, $C$ can't tell a lie now^_^

Comment: Why downvote? Is there something wrong here?

Comment: I've checked it. I don't think there is any mistake. Please make sure you have understood my proof.

Comment: FYI: The downvote was not from me.

Comment: @Clarinetist: Yes. I know. I left that comment for everyone who is watching.